# Passing list as an argument in wolfram mathematica

Tags: list, arguments, wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem. I need to calculate the mean, but I don't understand why the code below doesn't work. I read the documention and this function should accept a list and return the mean value. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I pass a list to a function this way?  How should I do it to get the correct result? 
Thank you in advance.

```
size = 15;
list = Table[0, {size}]; (*Declare a list*)
count = 0;
While[count < size,
     list[[count]] = 
     InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], RandomReal[]];
     count++
]  
Mean[list] (*Try to get the mean value*)
```

Comment: mathematica list indices start at 1.  you could use `RandomVariate` by the way.

Comment: Yes, I've already noticed that. Anyway, thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
size = 15;
list = Table[0, {size}];(*Declare a list*)
count = 1;
While[count <= size, 
 list[[count]] = InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], RandomReal[]];
 count++]
Mean[list] (*Try to get the mean value*)
```

Alternatively,

```
size = 15;
list = InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], RandomReal[{0, 1}, size]]
Mean[list]
```

since `InverseCDF` computes over a list, which can be observed by testing with symbolic variables:

```
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {a, b}]
```